# Добавить колонку данных из списка в dataframe pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Есть такой код:

```py
result_table = []
for url in urls_list:
    
    response = s2.get(url=url, headers=headers)
    soup2 = BS(response.text, 'lxml')

    
    try:
        table = pd.read_html(url) 
    
    except:
        print('table not exist')
        continue
    
    result_table.append(table)


final_table = pd.DataFrame() 

for t in result_table:

    final_table = final_table.append(t)

final_table.to_excel("razm.xlsx")
```

Итог выполнения кода условно выглядит вот так:

```
   Col1       Col2
0     1  RowTable1
1     2  RowTable1
2     3  RowTable2
3     4  RowTable2
4     5  RowTable3
```

затем мне необходимо строке типа `RowTable1` присвоить свое значение, чтобы итог выглядел вот так:

```
lst = [259, 178, 305]

   Col1       Col2
0   259  RowTable1
1   259  RowTable1
2   178  RowTable2
3   178  RowTable2
4   305  RowTable3
```

Я попробовала реализовать это следующим способом:

```py
lst = [259, 178, 305]
it = iter(lst)

final_table["Col1"] = final_table.groupby("Col2")["Col1"].transform(lambda x: [next(it, None)] * len(x))
```

Когда строк немного - все работает отлично, но когда их большое количество индексы из списка `lst` присваиваются не по порядку, а вразброс. Т.е. в первых строках - идет по порядку, затем  идет вразнобой. Хотя сами строки `RowTable`  - по порядку.
Никак не могу понять, в чем дело.

Использую:

- pandas: 1.3.1
- python: 3.8.0

Comment: Ошибка на наборе данных не воспроизводится. Откуда уверенность, что *строки RowTable - по порядку*? Можно привести воспроизводимый пример?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, как-то слишком хитро вы себе придумали.
Так-то проще и эффективнее будет вроде:

```py
import numpy as np
final_table["Col1"] = np.array(lst)[final_table.groupby("Col2").ngroup()]
```

Comment: спасибо - так сработало)) и правда намудрила я )